# Is it possible to extract specific words from a sentence in Hindi/Marathi?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, information-extraction

I have seen the different options to extract words from sentences in English but when I wanted to know if its possible to do the same thing in Hindi or Marathi

eg: टोमॅटो बेचना है

where the word at position 1 is TOMATO and it needs to be extracted i.e. extraction of product name from a sentence.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Can you please clarify the problem: are you trying to extract specific words provided as input or to separate the different words in  sentence? The latter is called word segmentation or tokenization, in case you're looking for tools to do it.

Comment: @Erwan I am trying to extract specific words in a sentence which may or may not be in the same format, its like looking for Nouns and extracting them from an english sentence

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I understand that you want to identify a particular syntactic category of words, for instance nouns. The task which identifies these categories is called [Part Of Speech (POS) tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging).

I'm not familiar with any specific resource for Hindi or Marathi but there are probably some software that you can use. From a quick search I found a few links below:

- [General resources for Indian languages](https://analyticsindiamag.com/top-nlp-libraries-datasets-for-indian-languages/)
- [A POS tagger for Hindi](https://github.com/rkp768/hindi-pos-tagger)
- [Another more recent POS tagger for Hindi](https://github.com/rootally/POS-Tagging-for-Hindi)